# Specify commit message with revert --continue

Tags: git, git-revert

How can I supply a message with the `revert --continue` command (i.e. after performing a revert and then resolving conflicts)?

`revert --continue` tries to pop up a message editor (fails on my system -- different question), but if I try this:

`git revert --continue -m "Reverted blah blah and resolved conflicts"`

I discover that `git revert` has a `-m` parameter for a different purpose.

I don't see any other message-related parameters in the documentation. Is there some common option not listed?

Comment: I would expect `--continue` to pick up where it left off before it had to deal with the merge conflicts, and not exactly be a spot where you add a message in.

Comment: @Makoto it's creating a commit for the changes made by the revert command and thus needs a commit message

Comment: Yes, but that happens once all commits up to the range you've specified have been successfully reverted.  `--continue` only really does anything [with the sequencer](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), and the end result of that would give you somewhere to commit and add your message.

Comment: @Makoto but then why would it be trying to run the message editor (gitpad in my case)?

Answer (score 27):

Run `git revert --no-commit <SHA>` and then `git commit -m "<message>"`

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Raman Zhylich's answer:

```
git revert <SHA>
git commit --amend -m "<message>"
```

or if you wanna get real fancy and actually append something to the merge-commit's message.

```
oldSubject="$(git log -1 --format="%s")"
oldBody="$(git log -1 --format="%b")"
git commit --amend -m "$(echo -e "$oldSubject\n\n$oldBody\n\nfootnote: I'm a good boy.")"
```